# pulling up a report for the current selected record in access 2010

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

I currently have a report called HoldTag that I put together that just displays some basic information about a product. I did it writing the query, saving that, then creating a report from that query.

On another form, I made a button that when clicked, is supposed to open that report and only display the info from the record that was being viewed when you click the button. The way I did that was to place the following in the click even handler in the code behind:

```
Private Sub btnPrintTag_Click()

Dim strReportname As String
Dim strCriteria As String

strReportname = "HoldTag"
strCriteria = "[ID] = & Me.ID"

DoCmd.OpenReport strReportname, acViewPreview, strCriteria


End Sub
```

When I click this button, the report launches, but it makes a page for every record on file. How do I make it only do it for the current record? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WhereCondition is the fourth argument to the [DoCmd.OpenReport Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff192676.aspx):

```
expression.OpenReport(ReportName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, WindowMode, OpenArgs)
```

But it looks to me like you're attempting to use a WhereCondition (*strCriteria*) as the third argument.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport strReportname, acViewPreview, strCriteria
```

Insert a comma so *strCriteria* is submitted as the fourth argument.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport strReportname, acViewPreview, , strCriteria
```

Comment: there we go. knew something didn't right. not used to not having intellisense help me out on overloaded methods. thanks :)